# Model to be used with only median data and weights

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, modeling, quantile-regression

I am finding a decent method to demonstrate if there is trend in the median age at diagnosis of multiple cancers. I do not have a breakdown of individual ages though, all I have is only (1) Median age at diagnosis by year, (2) Number of Cases and Population by year. (One of the cancer sites as below)

[image]

What statistics methodology I can use to prove or disprove the trend of median age? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this, I would probably ignore the changes in Cases and Population, and just use a robust or nonparametric method to determine if there is a slope of Age over Year, and to estimate that slope.  It's simple and easy for the audience to interpret.  It's probably also not worth it to try something more complex like auto-regressive time series.

One method is Sen's slope, which is nonparametric, and is often used in time series data. Another nonparametric test of trend is Mann-Kendall.  Alternately, you could use something like correlation or robust regression.

In the following R code, for the function I used for Sen's slope, the data are first transformed into a time series object.  But this isn't necessary for some other functions that calculate Sen's slope.

Note that the output gives you Sen's slope (0.5), a *p* value (0.001), and a 95% confidence interval for the slope.

```
if(!require(trend)){install.packages("trend")}

Data = read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Year Age Cases Population
2009  53  2945 3.69
2010  53  3014 3.73
2011  54  3419 3.82
2012  54  3508 3.85
2013  54  3524 3.85
2014  55  3524 3.89
2015  56  3868 3.93
2016  56  4108 3.96
2017  57  4373 4.00
")

TS = ts(Data$Age, frequency=1, start=2009)

library(trend)
sens.slope(TS)

   ### z = 3.2287, n = 9, p-value = 0.001243
   ### 95 percent confidence interval:
   ###  0.3333333 0.6666667
   ### sample estimates:
   ### Sen's slope 
   ###         0.5
```

You may not want to be too quick though, in reaching conclusions for this relationship.  For example, it is also the case that the incidence of cancer (`Prop` below, cases per 1000) increases over Year.  I don't know what to make of this.  Perhaps we are testing older people more over time, and so also are finding more incidents of cancer?

```
Data$Prop = round(Data$Cases / Data$Population / 1000, 3)

Data

   ###   Year Age Cases Population  Prop
   ### 1 2009  53  2945       3.69 0.798
   ### 2 2010  53  3014       3.73 0.808
   ### 3 2011  54  3419       3.82 0.895
   ### 4 2012  54  3508       3.85 0.911
   ### 5 2013  54  3524       3.85 0.915
   ### 6 2014  55  3524       3.89 0.906
   ### 7 2015  56  3868       3.93 0.984
   ### 8 2016  56  4108       3.96 1.037
   ### 9 2017  57  4373       4.00 1.093

cor.test(~ Age + Prop, data=Data)

   ### Pearson's product-moment correlation
   ### t = 9.1506, df = 7, p-value = 3.829e-05
   ###       cor 
   ### 0.961
```

As to the concern you raised in the answer by Demetri Pananos, I think the reality is that you can only work with the data you have.  If you have the median age, you can only report what you can determine about the median age.  You can't know if using the median was the best way to summarize the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can neither prove nor disprove anything in statistics.

Second, because you have median data, you can use quantile regression to model the median age of diagnosis as a function of time using the number of patients in each year diagnosed as a weight.  Here is an R script to do so

```
library(quantreg)

year = 2009:2017 - 2009
age = c(53,53,54,54,54,55,56,56,57)
w = c(2945,3014, 3419, 2508, 3524, 3868, 3900, 4108, 4373)

d=data.frame(year=year, age=age, w=w)

model = rq(age ~ year, data = d, weights = w)
summary(model)
```

This yeilds

```
Call: rq(formula = age ~ year, data = d, weights = w)

tau: [1] 0.5

Coefficients:
            coefficients lower bd upper bd
(Intercept) 52.50000     51.70021 53.10151
year         0.50000      0.39485  0.595
```

There definitely appears to be an increase in the age of diagnosis.  `quantreg` spits out `lower bd` and `upper bd`.  The documentation for quantreg says that `lower bd` and `upper bd` are confidence intervals.  Thus, it appears that the data are consistent with a non-zero effect of year, so I think you can confidently say that every two years, the median age of diagnosis increases by a year.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. How can we vigorously show that using median in the first hand does not affect the model fitting (or else, how does it affect the model and how can we justify that it is not problematic for the fit)?

Comment: @AaronLei Quantreg models the median of the data as opposed to the mean. You don’t have to worry about using the median since we are using tools which deal with the median.